# Python looping and creating separate lists

Tags: python

My main question is how to iterate through for/while loops changing the position of the starting elements. I have a small list of six elements

```
x= [34,37,38,36,38,43]
```

I want to create a distance matrix such that the first time it iterates through x it calculates the distance from 34 and stores those values as a list. Then the next time it starts from 37 and calculates the distance from there (now excluding 34, so each successive list will be one shorter than the previous).

I've started with code to initialize some things

```
x= [34,37,38,36,38,43]
x_list = []
i=1
k=i-1
```

Next, I run code

```
for i in range (i,len(x)):
    z = abs(x[i] - x[k])
    x_list.append(z)
```

Then I run the print statement to print off the list I want

```
print(x_list) #which returns correct output [3, 4, 2, 4, 9] for the first list
```

I now want the value of i to increase to 2 so that k=1 and when I iterate through the distances it should return [1, 1, 1, 6] in a separate list, but I'm not sure of how to do this since I've exited out of the loop and I don't want to hard-code i every time

Comment: I have a feeling the [enumerate function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) will help you out here. I simultaneously allows you to iterate through a list given you the list item AND the list index. More info [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a loop within a loop (a **nested** for loop).

```
x = [34,37,38,36,38,43]

for j in range (1, len(x)): # j from 1 to length-1
    k = j - 1 # we set the new k in the first outer loop
    x_list = [] # we reset x_list each time
    for i in range (j, len(x)): # i from j to len-1
        z = abs(x[i] - x[k]) # get the distances
        x_list.append(z)
    print(x_list) # print out the distances for each outer loop iteration
```

Outputs:

> [3, 4, 2, 4, 9]
>
> [1, 1, 1, 6]
>
> [2, 0, 5]
>
> [2, 7]
>
> [5]

If you want a slightly more complicated code that also saves the results with each iteration (by using a 2D list array), here's the code:

```
x = [34,37,38,36,38,43]

x_list = [[0] * 0 for i in range(len(x) - 1)] # generator makes us a 2D array

for j in range (1, len(x)): 
    k = j - 1 
    for i in range (j, len(x)): 
        z = abs(x[i] - x[k]) 
        x_list[j - 1].append(z) # notice we use the array to get the right list

for iteration in x_list: # loop through the x_list outer array
    print(iteration) # print out the distances for list
```

Outputs:

(Same as above)

Comment: Made an edit to the code so it prints out the distances in each loop

Answer (score 0):

You need two for loops for it.

```
x= [34,37,38,36,38,43]
out = [[abs(i-j) for j in x[n+1:]] for n, i in enumerate(x[:-1])]
print(out)
#prints
[[3, 4, 2, 4, 9], [1, 1, 1, 6], [2, 0, 5], [2, 7], [5]]
```